# SCSS first-child & last child

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Want to rotate one image to left, and then the other one to the right.

Something I really can't figure out why, the first part using last-child doesn't work, while the second works, any idea what the problem is?

Thanks!

```
<div>
    <img scr="pic-a.jpg"></img>
    <img scr="pic-b.jpg"></img>
</div>

img {
    width: 45%;
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    &:last-child {
        transform: rotate(-7deg);
    }
}
/* the above doesn't work */

img {
    width: 45%;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    &:first-child {
        transform: rotate(7deg);
    }
}

/* this works */
```

Comment: Are you sure this simplified code is equals to your real code? `first-child` can not work in case of `<img>` is really not first child of the `<div>` (there are some other div's children, not `<img>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else messing up your code, as I tried to reproduce your error, it seems to work for me in both ways. [Try it yourself](http://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/bBOjzQ).

One thing I also noticed was that your HTML is invalid. Your `src` attribute is misspelled and you don't need a closing `img` tag.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy, just really can't figure out what the problem is. I checked the codes in Chrome's console, by using &:last-child, the styles can't be applied to it, while using &:first-child, everything is fine.

Comment: And I also tried not using scss:

img {width: 45%; transform: rotate(7deg);}

img:last-child {transform: rotate(-7deg);}

This works as well, so I really have no idea what the problem can be, yet.